# d3.js index page visualization examples effect

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to do something like this page http://d3js.org/

Where do i find this hexagons effect visualization scripts?

I download the project, but i don't find any index.html page
Please help

Answer (score 0):

`d3.hexbin` is a D3.js plugin available on [GitHub](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/hexbin). Mike has a demo of the plugin on [bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7833311)